# Display value found at given address gdb

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, x86

I am debugging a binary file in gdb. It was C code compiled by gcc on an Intel IA-32. I retrieved this output from `objdump`. I am most interested in the last line here:

```
08048d9e <func_1>
8048d9e:    55                      push   %ebp
8048d9f:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048da1:    83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
8048da4:    c7 44 24 04 88 99 04    movl   $0x8049988,0x4(%esp)
8048dab:    08 
8048dac:    8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048daf:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048db2:    e8 54 01 00 00          call   8048f0b <strings_not_equal>
```

I believe this last line will compare the value found at the indicated address: `8048f0b`. I attempt:

```
(gdb) x 0x8048f0b
```

and receive:

```
0x8048f0b <strings_not_equal>:  0x57e58955
```

Am I interpreting the assembly incorrectly? Is this the correct way to read the value of an address in gdb? I was kind of expecting to find a more ascii friendly hex value. I am interested in finding the stored string value that is compared against.

Also do you have a favorite gui tool that you like to use for this type of debugging? I have been thinking about trying ddd. I want to find an easier way to debug.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are correctly reading the value at memory address `0x8048f0b`, but the line `call   8048f0b <strings_not_equal>` indicates that this address is the start of a function (called `strings_not_equal()`).  You wouldn't expect that to be ASCII - you'd expect it to be more machine code.

If you're looking for the function arguments to `strings_not_equal()`, those are being pushed onto the stack.  The first argument is being copied from `0x8(%ebp)`, which is the first argument of `func1()`.  The second argument is `$0x8049988`, which is presumably the address of a string.

If you want to print the contents of the address as a string, you can do that with `x/s`:

```
x/s 0x8049988
```

Comment: So in `phase_1` the first argument: `0x8(%ebp)` is stored on stack at `%eax`. This will also be an argument passed to `strings_not_equal`? How do you know the second argument to `strings_not_equal` is `$0x8049988`? Is it because it is written to `0x4(%esp)`?

Comment: so `x 0x8049988` gives `0x8049988 <__dso_handle+360>: 0x75742049` and `x/s 0x8049988` gives a long weird string as I would expect: `0x8049988 <__dso_handle+360>:  "I turned the moon into something I like to call a Death Star."` Don't we need 2 hex values to represent each ascii character? How did it translate that long string from `0x75742049`?

Comment: @KyleWeller: The first argument of `func_1()` is copied from `0x8(%esp)` into `%eax`, and then from `%eax` onto the stack where it will be picked up as the first argument of `strings_not_equal()`.  `0x8049988` is copied straight into the stack, where it will be picked up as the second argument of `strings_not_equal()`.  `x` without any format is displaying the first 4 bytes at the address as a 32-bit integer; those 4 bytes are the ASCII codes for I (`0x49`), space (`0x20`), t (`0x74`) and u (`0x75`).  As an integer the read in reverse order because your machine is *little-endian*.